# Does a gravitational lens around a body look 3-dimensional?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-lensing

Suppose we approach a neutron star or a stellar black hole close enough, is the gravitational lens around it 3-dimensional (like a tunnel) or is it 2-dimensional? It's 3-dimensional as if you entered a spacetime tunnel, isn't it? If you entered the tunnel, sidewards you'd see the firmament distorted too, right?

Comment: You'll get distortions in the shape of the field if the body is not spherical, or has asymmetric internal density variations.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger What do you mean by 'not spherical'? White dwarves, neutron stars and quark stars _are_ spherical. Do you mean black holes / singularities?

Comment: I'm thinking asteroids, moons, planets and the like. Doesn't really fit into your stellar question, but does put limits on when you can expect a spherical field. Come to think of it, rotating neutron stars do frame dragging, which would affect the symmetry of the gravitational field: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb&q=neutron+star+frame+dragging+gravitational+field&ia=web